# Flutter Firebase Messaging don't work on ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm running into a problem when using cloud_messaging and flutter_local_notifications in flutter. Notifications work on android platform but not on ios platform. I have implemented the docs on FlutterFire and pub.dev one by one. No matter what I did, I couldn't run it on ios.

My AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure()

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )
      } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      }
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
}
```

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'BSImagePicker'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

By the way, this is written in the console when the app is running on android. However, this is not visible in the application running on the iOS device.

> Flutter Firebase Messaging Background Service started!

My Notification Service class:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cocugumyanimda/cy_provider.dart';
import 'package:cocugumyanimda/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:cocugumyanimda/services/db/DatabaseHelper.dart';
import 'package:cocugumyanimda/services/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationService {
  static FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  static getToken(context) async {
    String? token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      var cyProvider = CYProvider.of(context);

      UserService _userService = cyProvider.userService;
      UserModel? user = await _userService.getUser();
      if (user != null) {
        var a = await _userService.sendToken(user.token, token);
        print(a.body.toString());
      } else {
        print("User is empty");
      }
    } else {
      print("TOKEN İS NULL");
    }

    print("TOKEN TAKEN $token");
  }

  static Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
      RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    if (message.data.isNotEmpty) {
      print('body ${message.data}');

      var data = message.data;
      if (data.isEmpty) return;
      var sender = data['gonderen'];

      var msg = data['mesaj'];
      var type = data['menu_type'];
      var senderId = data['id_gonderen'];

      if (type == "1") {
        sender = sender + " mesaj gönderdi";
      } else if (type == "0") {
        sender = sender + " paylaşımı yaptı";
      }

      // var query = await store.get(senderId);
      var query = await dbHelper.rawSelectBySender(senderId);

      // var sq = "db query is $query";
      // await Sentry.captureMessage(sq);
      if (query.isNotEmpty) {
        var id = query['_id'] as int;
        var count = query['count'] as int;
        count = count + 1;
        Map<String, dynamic> row = {
          DatabaseHelper.columnId: id,
          DatabaseHelper.columnCount: count,
          DatabaseHelper.columnSenderId: senderId,
        };
        var rt = await dbHelper.update(row);
        // var cid = await Sentry.captureMessage("row updated $row with id $rt");
        // print("sentry id $cid");
      } else {
        Map<String, dynamic> row = {
          DatabaseHelper.columnCount: 1,
          DatabaseHelper.columnSenderId: senderId,
        };
        var rs = await dbHelper.insert(row);

        // var cid = await Sentry.captureMessage("row inserted $row with id $rs");
        // print("sentry id $cid");
      }

      const androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'com.cocugumyanimda.cocugumyanimda',
        'Flutter chat demo',
        playSound: true,
        enableVibration: true,
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
      );

      const iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
          IOSNotificationDetails(presentAlert: true, presentSound: true, presentBadge: true);
      const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
      const IOSInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings = IOSInitializationSettings(requestAlertPermission: true);
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(InitializationSettings(iOS: iosInitializationSettings, android: androidInitializationSettings));
      const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
          iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0, sender, msg, platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: type == "1" ? senderId : "");
    }

    print(message.data.toString());
    print("Geldi");
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
static enableIOSNotifications() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> init() async {    
    
    
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
       await enableIOSNotifications();
      } else {
        print("not ios"); 
      }
    // getToken(context);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) async {
      print("Bildirim Geldi: " + event.data.toString());
    });

        FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);


    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) async {

      print("Bildirim Geldi: " + event.data.toString());
        });
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it on real iOS device or emulator?

Comment: I tested it from real device. I even tested it on test flight

Comment: Background and foreground notifications both missing on iOS, but both working on Android?

Comment: That's right, very strange issue

Comment: How can I solve it? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Is your app properly registered with Apple to receive notifications?

Comment: Yes I did all the integration.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @BeratKurt are you on an m1 mac?